# Trouble with Array Adapter for JSONArray

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, json

I am having trouble loading my JSON Array into my list. I basically just want it to load anything, but am having trouble getting it to even get to the getView part. Any help would be much appreciated...I've provided the code of the two relevant classes below.

I have the following main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static PostArrayAdapter mainAdapter;
    public static ArrayList<JSONObject> postArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="<<QUERY>>";

        Log.v("tag", "Logged this at least");

        JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.i("tag", "Response: " + response.toString());
                        try{
                            ArrayList<JSONObject> tempArray = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                            for(int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                tempArray.add(post);
                            }
                            postArray = tempArray;
                            Log.i("tag", "temp array: " + postArray.toString());
                            mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.e("Tag", "Error paring data "+e.toString());
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("tag", "Error: " + error.toString());
                    }
                });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            postArray = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            mainAdapter = new PostArrayAdapter(getActivity(), postArray);

            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_main);
            listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            Log.i("tag", "Logged this at least");
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

And the following ArrayAdapter class:

public class PostArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<JSONObject> posts;

public PostArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JSONObject> posts) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_main, posts);
    Log.i("tag", "Got Here 0");
    Log.i("tag", "Constructor response: " + posts.toString());
    this.context = context;
    this.posts = posts;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("tag", "Got Here 1A");
    try {
        Log.i("tag", "Got Here 1");
        JSONObject post = (JSONObject) this.posts.get(position);
        Log.i("tag", "Got Here 2");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.i("tag", "Got Here 3");
        Log.i("tag", "Post: " + post.toString());


        if (post.get("post_type").equals("post")) {
            Log.i("tag", "post");
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, parent, false);
            TextView postText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.postText);
            postText.setText("hello");
            return rowView;
        } else if (post.get("post_type").equals("meme")) {
            Log.i("tag", "meme");
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_meme, parent, false);
            return rowView;
        } else if (post.get("post_type").equals("poll")) {
            Log.i("tag", "poll");
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poll, parent, false);
            return rowView;
        } else if (post.get("post_type").equals("reply")) {
            Log.i("tag", "reply");
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_reply, parent, false);
            TextView replyText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.replyText);
            replyText.setText("hello");
            return rowView;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I know that the JSONArray is returning the correct response. Where I am having trouble is that it does not seem that the adapter is updating the value after I get the response. Does anyone have any possible solutions? In fact, "Got Here 1A" is never even being called (probably because it doesn't update after the adapter notifies of change)

Comment: getView can't return null

Comment: Try `View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, null, false);`

Comment: "Got Here 1A" is never even being called. I think the problem is before if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the data to the adapter? I didn't find related method in your code.

Before `mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` add `mainAdapter.addAll(postArray)`;